# SQL Server 2012 - Retrieve value where date is between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table called 'Rates':

```
Valid From     Employee      Rate
----------------------------------
01/03/2010     1M            50
01/03/2010     2M            75
01/10/2015     1M            55
01/10/2015     2M            80
```

I also have the following table called 'Jobs':

```
ID        Employee         OpenedDate     Rate
100000    1M               05/06/2012
100000    2M               08/09/2018
```

How do I retrieve the rate from the Rates table into the Jobs table, where the OpenedDate is greater than or equal to the current ValidFrom date and less than or equal to the next ValidFrom date, where the Employee also matches?

So I would end up with:

```
ID        Employee         OpenedDate     Rate
100000    1M               05/06/2012     50
100000    2M               08/09/2018     80
```

Hope I explained that okay
Cheers for any and all help!

ps not sure how to display the above data as a table layout in Stack, been looking through the help but I cant see how??

Comment: Whilst this is not impossible, it would be made a lot easier and optimise the queries if you were to introduce a `ValidTo` field instead of relying on looking up the `ValidFrom` date in a different row.

Comment: Would love to be able to but its an application that cannot be changed. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't modify the table to add a "ValidTo" column then you'll have to create one dynamically using `LEAD` Window function

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Valid From] DATETIME, Employee varchar(2), Rate int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Valid From], Employee, Rate)
VALUES
    ('2010-01-03 00:00:00', '1M', 50),
    ('2010-01-03 00:00:00', '2M', 75),
    ('2015-01-10 00:00:00', '1M', 55),
    ('2015-01-10 00:00:00', '2M', 80)
;

CREATE TABLE Table2
    (ID int, Employee varchar(2), OpenedDate DATETIME, Rate int)
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (ID, Employee, OpenedDate, Rate)
VALUES
    (100000, '1M', '2012-05-06 00:00:00', NULL),
    (100000, '2M', '2018-08-09 00:00:00', NULL)
;

;WITH cteValidToAdded
AS(
    SELECT
         T1.[Valid From]
        ,[ValidTo] = ISNULL(LEAD(T1.[Valid From])OVER(PARTITION BY T1.Employee ORDER BY T1.[Valid From], T1.Employee),'25001212') --Some date in distance future
        ,T1.Employee
        ,T1.Rate 
    FROM dbo.Table1 T1
)
SELECT 
     T2.ID
    ,T2.Employee
    ,OpenedDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), T2.OpenedDate, 101)
    ,V.Rate
FROM dbo.Table2 T2
LEFT JOIN cteValidToAdded V ON V.Employee = T2.Employee 
                            AND T2.OpenedDate >= V.[Valid From] AND T2.OpenedDate < V.ValidTo
```

Output

```
ID      Employee    OpenedDate  Rate
100000  1M          05/06/2012  50
100000  2M          08/09/2018  80
```

Comment: I was writing up this very solution but you got it done a little faster.

Comment: You'll beat me next time I'm sure @JoeFarrell :-)

Comment: Do you need to order by Employee in the `LAG` expression (since you're partitioning by employee anyways)?

Comment: Just a style note. Since you're already terminating your statements with a semi-colon, you don't need to lead your CTE definition with one. The _actual_ requirement is that the statement preceding the CTE must be terminated with a semi-colon, which an unfortunate number of people have mis-translated into _opening_ a CTE with a semi-colon. </Soapbox>

Comment: @EricBrandt absolutely. It is a statement terminator, not a statement beginninator. One of those times where it can really make a mess of things is in a table valued function. If you begin with a semi-colon you will have syntax errors that will drive you nuts.

Comment: @SeanLange, +1 (for a second time, I think) for "beinninator". Makes me laugh every time I see you use it.

Comment: @EricBrandt I wish I could take credit it. I first heard the term from Lynn Pettis at sql server central. But it is hilarious!!!

Comment: Yes you're both right. I included it because if I don't then sometimes, if the OP doesn't know the syntax rule, when they copy the cte bit of the answer and include it in their code they come saying its error'd

Comment: Thanks for this guys, I will test asap and reply back. I can create a view in the database, so this should do the trick with a view.

Comment: @Mazhar Thanks for this, the only thing I had to change was to make OpenedDate >= ValidFrom date, to make sure borderline records are retrieved correctly. Otherwise, BRILLIANT! Didnt even know about this LEAD function. BTW I cant edit the answer as its less than 6 characters for the edit. Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad I could help @Naz

Answer (score 0):

Just use `outer apply`:

```
select j.*, r.rate
from jobs j outer apply
     (select top (1) r.*
      from rates r
      where r.employee = j.employee and
            r.valid_from <= j.opened_date
      order by r.valid_from desc
     ) r;
```

With an index on `rates(employee, valid_from)` (and maybe including `rate`), this should be faster than a version that uses window functions.